# Xamarin - how to open a new ContentPage in a ListView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a list that comes from my web service and i display it like so:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView x:Name="curso" ItemSelected="CursoView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label StyleClass="Header" Text="{Binding name}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And now i want to be able to click on an item and open a new ContentPage

Answer (score 2):

```
public void CursoView_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  // this assumes your current page is already contained in a NavigationPage
  Navigation.PushAsync(new MyNextPage());
}
```

Comment: That's my problem my current page isn't a NavigationPage

Comment: You can simply replace App.MainPage with a new page, but the user will have no way to navigate back

Comment: You could also display the new page modally if you are not interested in using a NavigationPage.

Comment: But now i have lets say 3 item on my list. How can i make them push a new page depending on the item the user clicks on?

Comment: use e.ItemSelected